Could not deserialize 'application/json'
Here is my UserRequest model class, I am getting a SerializationException:
[Route("/somepath", Verbs = "POST")]
public class ABCRequest
{
    public List<UserRequest> Requests { get; set; }
}

public class UserRequest
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}

This is my JSON body :
[
    {
      "UserID": 123,
      "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
      "ToDate": "2016-01-01T23:59:59"
    },
    {
      "UserID": 456,
      "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
      "ToDate": "2016-01-01T23:59:59"
    }
]

I am getting a serialization exception:

Could not deserialize 'application/json'
Error: Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'ABCRequest', got string starting with: [, {, "UserId": 123,
"From",

I have also tried this in the body:
{
  "Requests": [
    {
      "UserID": 123,
      "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
      "ToDate": "2016-01-01T23:59:59"
    },
    {
      "UserID": 456,
      "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
      "ToDate": "2016-01-01T23:59:59"
    }
  ]
}

Using this I am getting Request Dto is not supported. What is wrong with the body for the requests?
Here is the code where the request being passed:
public async Task<SomeResponse> Post(ABCRequest request) 
{ var responses = new List<someResponse>(); 
  foreach (var userRequest in request.Requests) 
  {
   // remaining code
  }
}

Here is the full code of my Post Method:
public async Task<SomeResponse> Post(ABCRequestRequest request)
{
    var responses = new List<GetSomeResponse>();
    foreach (var userRequest in request.Requests)
    {
        var userSummaries = await someService.GetSummaryAsync(
            userRequest.UserID, m userRequest.FromDate.ToString(),  userRequest.ToDate.ToString());

        var data = userSummaries
            .Where(data => data.SomeData != 0)
            .Select(data =>
            {
                return data;
            }).ToList();

        var response = new GetSomeResponse
        {
            UserID = userRequest.UserID
        };
        responses.Add(response);
    }
    return new SomeResponse
    {
        Responses = responses
    };
}


Show the code you're using to send the request. I suspect in the place where you're supposed to set the request's content-type, you're setting the request's content to application/json.

Here is the Code where the request is used :  public async Task Post(ABC request)
{
var responses = new List();
foreach (var userRequest in request.Requests)
{ // remaining code}}

Your post method needs to take an array of UserRequest, aka Post(UserRequest[] request)

@wax, You don't need to deserialize your request. It can be use directly. If you want to convert into JSON then you need to serialize first.

@AbhayDedkawala how can I modify the body to take the request directly? I used the two samples listed above and got the exception. For rene's comment -  the actual class is the ABCRequest that has a list of UserRequest.

@wax, Your second JSON body is right as per your Post method. Can you edit this post & add extra code of Post method & also from which line you get this error.

@AbhayDedkawala I have added the full code of my POST method.

it seems it is because of the token issue when authenticating to my endpoint. When I commented out the [Authenticate] tag this payload works :   {
"requests": [
{
"userID": 0,
"fromDate": "2024-07-25T15:08:58.003Z",
"toDate": "2024-07-25T15:08:58.003Z"
}
]
}

It seems it was a problem with the [Authenticate] tag.  When I comment out the tag this payload works :
{
  "requests":
  [
    {
      "userID": 0,
      "fromDate": "2024-07-25T15:08:58.003Z",
      "toDate": "2024-07-25T15:08:58.003Z"
    }
  ]
}


You'll want to dig into your authentication configuration to understand why the [Authenticate] tag led to this problem. Don't just disable authentication to make things work.
